# Loading youtube video in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, video, youtube

I have in my homepage different content articles which may contain videos. If an article contains video, the video icon beneath it will redirect to Video.aspx page which contains a  to play the video. My Video.aspx is like:

```
<div class="mainvideo" id="video" runat="server">
<iframe id="videoPlayer" runat="server" width="628" height="374" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
```

The videos are managed in youtube and each article contains the youtube url. I tried to set src to the iframe from code behind which didn't work.

```
string articleID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();

        ClassArticleContents objArticleContent = new ClassArticleContents();
        objArticleContent.ArticleID = Convert.ToInt32(articleID);
        objArticleContent = objArticleContent.GetArticleByID();
        if (objArticleContent != null)
    videoPlayer.Attributes.Add("src", objArticleContent.videoURL);
```

I also tried to build the innerhtml for the div with iframe

```
video.InnerHtml = "<iframe width='628' height='374' src='" + objArticleContent.videoURL + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Both of this didn't show the videoplayer in Video.aspx page. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: In your second code snippet, what is videoPlayer?

Comment: Sorry it is the id for iframe

Comment: Can you paste the code or the objArticleContent.videoURL, as that's probably incorrect. Remember the youtube embed link is like: http://youtube.com/embed/video_id

Comment: And where is that code placed in the code behind?

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That was my bad that I was using the youtube url rather than the embed url.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a literal and add that to a panel ?

```
Literal videoFrame = new Literal();

videoFrame.Text = string.Format(@"<iframe width=""628"" height=""374"" src=""{0}"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe>", objArticleContent.videoURL);
panel.controls.add(videoFrame);
```

Just to be sure check what objArticleContent.videoURL equals.